# Excel VBA dynamic range fill down

Tags: excel, vba

I have a weekly report which gets added to the bottom of a running report at the start of the week.

I need to be able to fill down the date in column A with a dynamic start point to the end of the data that has just been pasted into columns B:AB.

I need the date to be 1 week from the last date entered, not TODAY because if the report is run on a Tuesday (due to a public holiday on Monday), I want the Monday date entered.

I have managed to get what I need apart from filling down column A from the dynamic start point to the last entry in column B.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

`copy and paste weekly data into running total`
    Sheets("Weekly Appt Data").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Appointment Data").Select
    Range("Main[[#Headers],[Dealer Name]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    
    
`enter new date`

    Range("Main[[#Headers],[Date]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False



`fill down date to end.
I need to be able to fill down column A here.  The following is not correct but is the closest I have seen but A2 will not work because the start position changes every week and the amount to fill down could change every week.`


    With Sheets("Weekly Appt Data")
    .Range("A2").AutoFill .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
    
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of code copies data from "Weekly Appt Data" to "Appointment Data". I think you are going to fill column A on "Appointment Data". Updated the sheet name as needed if I were wrong.

```vb
    ' enter new date
    Dim c As Range
    With Sheets("Appointment Data")
        ' Get the cell which has the last date entered
        Set c = .Range("Main[[#Headers],[Date]]").End(xlDown)
        ' Fill column A with new date
        .Range(c.Offset(1, 0), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1)).Value = c.Value + 7
    End With
```

The first part can be optimized w/o using copy/paste.

Note: the code have NOT been tested.

```
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDes As Range
    With Sheets("Weekly Appt Data")
        Set rSrc = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    End With
    With Sheets("Appointment Data")
        Set rDes = .Range("Main[[#Headers],[Dealer Name]]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        rDes.Resize(rSrc.Rows.Count, rSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rSrc.Value
    End With
```

Comment: You are right. It's a typo. I updated the code for the first part too to improve efficiency.

Comment: This code works great @taller, but I was wondering if you can assist with one issue.  Sometimes there are less rows than the previous week and it appears if there are less lines than the previous week it will insert blank lines at the end.
Is there a way to not insert the blank lines if there are less lines this week?

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) The answer is yes. I would suggest you create a new post with sample data ( or screenshot ). It's helpful for revising code.